# Hosting of WCF and Windows Services

Tags: vb.net, wcf, service, hosting

My head hurts so much I think I need a bottle of aspirin...

I've created a WCF service and, with help of others from this site and the department I work in, the WCF service is running as a service on my development machine. Tested it with a console app and it works.

But, it's not supposed to be on my development machine. It needs to be on a different server.

This is difficult because the server it is supposed to reside on DOES NOT have Visual Studio installed on it.

So I cannot run the VS 2008 Command Prompt with installutil to run the WCF service as a service on that server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Broadly speaking, you've got three options, all of which are described on MSDN:

- [Host the service under IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx)
- [Self-host the service in any managed .NET application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx)
- [Host the WCF service under a Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx)

Which one is right for you depends on what your service is for, how it'll be consumed, how scalable and secure you need the set-up to be, and a dozen other things besides. Without knowing a bit more about what your service does and how it'll be used in your organisation, it's difficult to make a recommendation.

IIS hosting is easy to set up and is the way to go if you want to leverage all of the industrial-strength hosting functionality that a full-blown web server offers.

Self-hosting is quick and easy - you can knock out a WCF-hosting console app in two minutes flat - but is the clunky solution. You of course have to run the host application as a particular Windows user. Perhaps not ideal?

Hosting under a Windows service is the middle ground. It gives you that always-available functionality without having to be logged in as a specific user, but doesn't offer the configurability and scalability of the IIS solution. It takes a bit more effort than belting out a quick console app, but not much.

Comment: This is the problem. When visiting MSDN they give an 'example', shown here -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx. Although there is SOME VB code, the document was written for C. I don't get cs files, or classes when creating a console app. I get vb files and MODULES. I keep getting directed to those links -- which are completely useless. I need a straight-forward, VB example of hosting WCF as a Windows Service.

Comment: @Jason: Well, i'd add that info to your question if I were you. :)

Comment: @Jason: I've edited my hyperlinks to point at equivalent MSDN pages with VB code examples.

Comment: @Jason: And I've retagged the question so that it gets some attention from the vb community.

Comment: Same issue on those links. If you look at step 2, it's asking you to rename a file from 'Program.cs' to 'Service.cs'. Out here in VB land we aren't issued cs files when we start new console apps. Those examples have some VB equivalents from C, but it is NOT a step-by-step guide for VB. Won't work (I have been working with it all day). But thanks anyways!

Comment: @Jason: you could always use one of the several online "C#-to-VB.NET" converters to get VB.NET code, if you can't read and understand C#. Try this one for instance: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Answer (score 2):

The server that the windows service will reside on will have the .NET Framework. INSTALLUTIL is located in the Microsoft.NET\Framework(version number) folder in the Windows directory.

For example, C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727.

No need to write a console app to host your service now (unless you want to).

Answer (score 0):

You can also host your WCF service under IIS, check this out: [MSDN - How to: Host a WCF Service in IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx). It really is just a five minute job :)

Comment: The other server does not, and will not, have IIS. If it did, my life would be so much easier!

Comment: @Jason - it might be time to jump up and down and demand IIS (if it is a newer version of Windows Server it will already be there, it just needs to be enabled). It will make your life a whole lot easier :)

Comment: Thanks, but tried that. They installed and then uninstalled IIS. I think the goal of this is to make my life as difficult as possible :-(

Comment: This link gave what I needed: http://joefreeman.co.uk/blog/2010/03/creating-a-setup-project-for-a-windows-wcf-service-with-visual-studio/